# How to hash the contents of a file uploaded in Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, html, hash, meteor

I'm just starting out with Meteor and (and coding in general) I have done the tutorial projects and examples etc and am looking to start my own project. My project is I want users to be able to select a file on their computer with an  field, user selects file, the contents of the file is read and the webpage provides a hash of the contents. Possible to be done clientside without the file being uploaded to a server?

A bit lost where I should be looking- HTML5 file-read API, cryptoJS, or something else? How would I go about providing that functionality in a webpage?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done using the HTML5 FileReader API.

```
Template.fileUpload.helpers({
  'change #file': function (e) {
     var files = e.target.files;
     var file = files[0];           
     var reader = new FileReader();
     reader.onload = function() {
       console.log(this.result);
     }
     reader.readAsText(file);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. Hm, on further investigation the HTML5 Filereader API seems that I can only read certain contents about the file like name, size and type. This won't enable me to make a unique hash of the contents of the file.